# Caffe Installation error

Tags: linker, caffe

I am installing Caffe on Ubunutu 15.04. I installed all the prerequisites mentioned in the installation page of Caffe from the official page: http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html

I am getting error during make. I am posting the error log (could not post whole log, too big a file. I cropped messages from starting till it fits the block). Please inform me if this is not useful

```
g++ src/caffe/util/math_functions.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/math_functions.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/math_functions.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/math_functions.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.cpp
g++ src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/util/db.cpp
g++ src/caffe/util/db.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/db.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/db.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.cpp
g++ src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/util/hdf5.cpp
g++ src/caffe/util/hdf5.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/util/insert_splits.cpp
g++ src/caffe/util/insert_splits.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/insert_splits.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/insert_splits.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/insert_splits.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/util/cudnn.cpp
g++ src/caffe/util/cudnn.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/cudnn.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/cudnn.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/cudnn.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp
g++ src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/net.cpp
g++ src/caffe/net.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/net.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/net.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/net.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/common.cpp
g++ src/caffe/common.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/common.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/common.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/common.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
AR -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a
ar rcs .build_release/lib/libcaffe.a .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o .build_release/src/caffe/internal_thread.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/nesterov_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adagrad_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o .build_release/src/caffe/solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/syncedmem.o .build_release/src/caffe/layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/parallel.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/batch_norm_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/filter_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/reduction_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/argmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/embed_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lcn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/spp_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/dummy_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/batch_reindex_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/power_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/log_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/reshape_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/split_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/base_conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o .build_release/src/caffe/blob.o .build_release/src/caffe/data_reader.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/benchmark.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/im2col.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/signal_handler.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/math_functions.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/insert_splits.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/cudnn.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o .build_release/src/caffe/net.o .build_release/src/caffe/common.o
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so
g++ -shared -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.o .build_release/src/caffe/internal_thread.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/nesterov_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/sgd_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adagrad_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/rmsprop_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adam_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/solvers/adadelta_solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/data_transformer.o .build_release/src/caffe/solver.o .build_release/src/caffe/syncedmem.o .build_release/src/caffe/layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/parallel.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/multinomial_logistic_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lrn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hinge_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/batch_norm_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/mvn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/pooling_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_pooling_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/dropout_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/bnll_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_sigmoid_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/hdf5_output_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/deconv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/neuron_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/filter_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/softmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/reduction_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/argmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/slice_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_relu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/contrastive_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/embed_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/image_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/memory_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/flatten_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_lcn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/inner_product_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/tile_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/softmax_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/threshold_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_softmax_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/spp_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/prelu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/euclidean_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/dummy_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/infogain_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/accuracy_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/tanh_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/lrn_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/im2col_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_cross_entropy_loss_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/relu_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/silence_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/batch_reindex_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/absval_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/power_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/log_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/reshape_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/eltwise_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/exp_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/cudnn_tanh_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/concat_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/base_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/window_data_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/split_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/base_conv_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layers/sigmoid_layer.o .build_release/src/caffe/layer_factory.o .build_release/src/caffe/blob.o .build_release/src/caffe/data_reader.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/upgrade_proto.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/io.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/benchmark.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/im2col.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/signal_handler.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/math_functions.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_lmdb.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/db_leveldb.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/hdf5.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/insert_splits.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/cudnn.o .build_release/src/caffe/util/blocking_queue.o .build_release/src/caffe/net.o .build_release/src/caffe/common.o -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas 
CXX tools/finetune_net.cpp
g++ tools/finetune_net.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/finetune_net.o 2> .build_release/tools/finetune_net.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/finetune_net.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/finetune_net.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/finetune_net.o -o .build_release/tools/finetune_net.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/device_query.cpp
g++ tools/device_query.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/device_query.o 2> .build_release/tools/device_query.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/device_query.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/device_query.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/device_query.o -o .build_release/tools/device_query.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/caffe.cpp
g++ tools/caffe.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/caffe.o 2> .build_release/tools/caffe.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/caffe.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/caffe.o -o .build_release/tools/caffe.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp
g++ tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.o 2> .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.o -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_binary.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/extract_features.cpp
g++ tools/extract_features.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.o 2> .build_release/tools/extract_features.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/extract_features.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/extract_features.o -o .build_release/tools/extract_features.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp
g++ tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.o 2> .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.o -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_net_proto_text.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/test_net.cpp
g++ tools/test_net.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/test_net.o 2> .build_release/tools/test_net.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/test_net.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/test_net.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/test_net.o -o .build_release/tools/test_net.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/convert_imageset.cpp
g++ tools/convert_imageset.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.o 2> .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.o -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.cpp
g++ tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.o 2> .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.o -o .build_release/tools/upgrade_solver_proto_text.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/compute_image_mean.cpp
g++ tools/compute_image_mean.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.o 2> .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.o -o .build_release/tools/compute_image_mean.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/net_speed_benchmark.cpp
g++ tools/net_speed_benchmark.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/net_speed_benchmark.o 2> .build_release/tools/net_speed_benchmark.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/net_speed_benchmark.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/net_speed_benchmark.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/net_speed_benchmark.o -o .build_release/tools/net_speed_benchmark.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
CXX tools/train_net.cpp
g++ tools/train_net.cpp -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/tools/train_net.o 2> .build_release/tools/train_net.o.warnings.txt \
        || (cat .build_release/tools/train_net.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/train_net.bin
g++ .build_release/tools/train_net.o -o .build_release/tools/train_net.bin -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -DUSE_OPENCV -DUSE_LEVELDB -DUSE_LMDB -DCPU_ONLY -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -lcaffe -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/lib -L.build_release/lib  -lglog -lgflags -lprotobuf -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lm -lhdf5_hl -lhdf5 -lleveldb -lsnappy -llmdb -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lboost_thread -lstdc++ -lcblas -latlas \
        -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../lib
ln: target ‘.build_release/tools/finetune_net’ is not a directory
Makefile:592: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/finetune_net' failed
make: *** [.build_release/tools/finetune_net] Error 1
```

How should I proceed with this ?

Edit: I am also posting my Makeconfig.config file (only the uncommented part)

Comment: can you post your `Makefile.config` file?

Comment: @Shai : I have updated my Makeconfig.config file

Comment: Can you try commenting the last ine and re-build? should give a more detailed output to find this issue,

Answer (score 0):

The error show that your file ./tools/finetune_net.cpp may be not exist or be with wrong path.I advise you check that file first.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure OpenCv is installed and the Makefile is edited for the installed version

Answer (score 0):

The installation of caffe can be a problem sometimes, that is why authors have published a Docker image. I would suggest to use it, it works great.

Assuming you have docker installed (https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/):

```
cd caffe/docker
docker build -t caffe:cpu standalone/cpu
```

Then, you can access via:

```
docker run -ti -v /path/to/folder/conf_and_images_for_caffe/:/datas caffe:cpu bash
```

(the -v option let you mount a volume on the docker container to work with files from your computer)